# Twitter Account Activity API webhook - How to determine which type of event occurred

Tags: twitter, webhooks

Hey whatup all you people. Question about the payload sent to a Twitter Account Activity API webhook. According to the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/account-activity-data-objects#tweet_create_events) I could find, TweetObjects for the the following events are all included under the `tweet_create_events`:

> Tweet status payload when any of the following actions are taken by or to the subscription user: Tweets, Retweets, Replies, @mentions, QuoteTweets, Retweet of Quote Tweets.

Looks like for `@mentions` there is an additional key `user_has_blocked` included, but besides that, is there any way to tell if the event was a Tweet vs. Retweet vs. a Reply, etc?

I assume there must be, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Alright here's what I figured out from testing all the scenarios.

The twitter user who initiated the event can be found in

`tweet.user`

It's a Reply if :

`tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str != null`

It's an @Mention if:

`tweet.in_reply_to_user_id != null && tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str == null`

It's a Retweet if:

`tweet.retweeted_status != null`

It's a Quote if:

`tweet.is_quote_status == true`

Otherwise, it's a Tweet.